# XSD Derive Restrictions/Enumerations of Attribute

Tags: xml, dom, vba, xsd, xml-parsing

I have an XSD file (schema layout for an XML file) which has restrictions/enumerations for certain fields. E.g. my attribute is entitled "Car" and only certain values ("Honda", "Ford", "GMC", "Toyota", etc) are allowed.

Is there a method using MSXML and/or the DOM XML model within VBA (or any other language) to derive the restrictions ("Honda", "Ford", "GMC", "Toyota", etc) for an attribute/node ("Car") from an XSD?

The ideal end state/my goal is to write a function after loading an XSD/Map where the xpath location of a node is passed in string format (e.g. "/Root/Car") and a string array is returned with the allowable fields for that node!

Any insight or references are greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any 'easy' solution - I did something similar to what you are describing but 'manually' - i.e. writing quite a lot of code.

The only library I was able to find that does something like that is this: http://xpath-on-schema.sourceforge.net/, but I did not actually try it because is Java-based and I am a .NET person.

If you are OK developing something in .NET my suggestion would be to use the `XmlSchema` class:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(xsdPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
   XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(fs, null);
}
```

and then there are relatively-easy-to-use methods and classes to access everything you need in the schema - e.g. there is a class `XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction` corresponding to a restriction on a simple type like a string, that contains in the `Facets` property the list of admissible values (or other restrictions).